# React relative href not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Am very new to react app. Created one react app with router and all. Everything is working fine in dev mode. I ran npm run build and try to run index.html from build folder. All the href got broke. I know something messed up with router. i don't know how to fix it. Here i post my code which give you more understanding/

NavBar.jsx

```
<NavItem eventKey={3} href="/login">
        Login
      </NavItem>
```

Note NavBar.jsx is not inside router.

Package.json

```
"version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
"homepage": "./",
```

When i host in local IIS, my home page URL is

> http://localhost/testing/index.html#/

When i click login button it navigate to

> http://localhost/login

In package.json anything i need to change? i go through google someone advised to change anchor tag to router Link tag. But in my case NavBar is outside of router,here am not able to change and also many place am programmatically redirect to new URL, so its very difficult for changing all the places.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"login"` instead of `"/login"`

```
<NavItem eventKey={3} href="login">
        Login
      </NavItem>
```